# Limit the number of bullets unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using [Advanced Sniper Starter Kit](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7593) that fires bullets. but I would like to limit the number of bullets in each level of games. For example, In my first level I need only 10 bullets and in second level suppose I need only 20 bullets. Please anyone can help me.

Comment: To Enhance the Bullet code, Show yours code first.

Comment: You need to create a script with public variable of game-object (a prefab assign to this variable which need to spawn. in your case it is bullet) and public Int variable for quantity. Apply this script to any object of your scene game-object and in next scene assign this again to any game-objet and change the quantity from inspector.

Comment: Unfortunately, since "Advanced Sniper Starter Kit" is not a free asset, it is difficult for us to work out a solution for you if you don't show us any code you have written so far (as we likely don't have access to this asset). Please give us a bit more to work with - otherwise, the answers/comments you've already gotten are probably the most help we can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable in every level which contains the maximum number of bullets.

Comment: Sorry that is not the complete answer. Ok I declare a global variable, but whoes script I declare that variable, like enemy script, player script. And how to control bullets through this variable.

Comment: I would create a Script for a level, you can access global variables in other scripts, so when you shoot (try to) you check if the max number of bullets >= 0 and if so shoot and subtract 1 from the maximum number of bullets.

Comment: ' if (Level name == " XXX")  then if (BulletCount < 20) then Fire; ++BulletCount'  Do this for all level

Comment: Now I got it. But I am using advance sniper kit, I don't knows where is the shoot function. And Advance sniper kit use unlimited number of bullets. Where I see the number of bullets that sniper kit uses, and In shoot function I control the bullets.

Comment: Because I can't see shoot function in player script. character motor, FPSInput Controler, Gun Handdle, FPS Controller, these are the scripts that attached to player. Mind in these function are predefined comes with Player (advance sniper kit). I don't see shoot function in all these scripts.

Comment: I think you don't write any code. You need to write attack code first. Inside of fire you can check number of bullets left which are in the Global Variable etc. Then if the condition is ok you let the player fire.

Comment: AS_Bullet.cs
 AS_BulletHiter.cs Check where these scripts,  if there then Disable that and check Firing or not

Comment: Yes in As_Bullet script. When I uncheck that script player cant fire. Now please go ahead and help me to the correct problem.

Comment: @Saqib Leghari - Sorry I dont have that project and AS_Bullet script to help you. Just I checked  Script names in Asset store thats it.